# Replacing string with a function that outputing data already

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to replace a string with a function which already displays data or you can echo data already

```php
    function getData(){
        //echoing data from database, loop
        echo 'printing output';
    }

     function output(){
        return getData();
    }
```

And here is the string

```php
    $str = "This is some text with php code <?php output();?>";
```

I tried str_replace like this

```
str_replace("<?php output();?>", output(), $str);
```

The problem is that it displays data already when I `str_replace` to replace the code with function. And i also tried other function like `preg_replace()` and `preg_replace_callback()`

Comment: You are running the function `output()`. Try putting the function in quotes. `$str = str_replace("<?php output();?>", "output()", $str);`

Comment: already did that

Comment: @Thefourthbird and that prints  This is some text with php code output()

Comment: @Thefourthbird it should print  "printing output" from that function

Comment: The code is searching for string `"<?php output();?>"` and tries to replace it with NULL in the string `"This is some text with php code <?php output();?>"` The functions getData and output are not returning anything.

Comment: @Thefourthbird thats the problem, i want to replace "<?php output();?>" with a function so i can print it and it should also run this function with output

Comment: @Thefourthbird getData and output() returns data when you call the replace function

Comment: getData should return the string instead of echoing it, so, output should return the result of getData. Right now you're replacing the code with the result of a function that is not returning anything.

Comment: @Triby getData will return data from database and  returns the loop, returning string is not what i want.

Comment: Ok, update your question, make the output function return something and it will work, at least with this code.

Comment: @Triby still it will call the function before you replace it

Comment: No, what's happening here is that getData is echoing the string instead of returning it and that's why you see that text before the replacement.

Comment: @Triby yes this is what meant

Comment: If getData echoes content you can't do the replacement, unless you use ob_* functions to buffer and get contents inside the output function. Read this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output function must return contents from getData:

```
function getData(){
    //echoing data from database, loop
    echo 'printing output';
}

 function output(){
    // Start buffer
    ob_start();
    // Call the function and store its contents on buffer
    getData();
    // Get buffer, clean buffer and return contents
    return ob_get_clean();
}
// The string
$str = "This is some text with php code <?php output();?>";
// Replace and output
echo str_replace("<?php output();?>", output(), $str);
```

Comment: do i have ob_get_flush the buffer? Thank you for your answer. And the other who don't know the answer just came and down voted the question lol

Comment: No, ob_get_flush() works a little different returning the contents of the buffer, but sending them to the browser too.